# How to display the selected contact person (selected from address book: ABPickeView ) name as well along with the number in the text filed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, abaddressbook, abpeoplepickerview

I have implemented an **iPhone app..**

in that i have two options **1. Send SMS 2.Send email** in a page.

I implemented both functionalities and

**Implemented code to get address book when taping on contacts text fields or on a discloser button.**

[image]

From hte addresss book user can pick the contact and it will be displayed in the text field.

Now **`i need to display the selected contact person name as well along with the number in the text filed.`**

as follows for name **DAVID**

[image]

How

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the person as ABRecordRef => if not please just show me your code to help you =>

then you could just do something like:

`NSString* compositeName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef)record);`

to get the compositeName. Its a human friendly composite name.